# How to load google map on modal load with php <?php $row['address'] ?> address pulled from MySQLi database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a modal that pops up with Customer name, address, & other information and includes a box displayed on the modal with a google map.  I want to be able to popup the modal with the google map loaded with the Customers address displayed with the marker pin.

Currently the map loads but is not the location of the Customers address.  I have to click an UPDATE button in order for the map to change to the Customers address w/Marker pin and that does work, but I would like this to auto load and not have to click the UPDATE button.

Thanks in advance for the help..

```
    //This is in the <head> section of index.php

    // Google Maps API ******************************************* -->
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
            key=YOURKEY=initMap"></script>

     // Google Maps ------>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/GoogleMaps.js"></script>

    //Here is javascript file: GoogleMaps.js
    <script>
     function initMap() {
          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
          });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
      geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
    });
  }

  function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: resultsMap,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + 
      status);
      }
    });
  }
   </script>


   //In the <body> I have the following display box for the map
   <div id="map" style="width: 300px; height: 160px; border-radius: 6px;"> 
    </div>


  // In the modal-footer I have the following button that currently updates the map with the 
     Customers address:

  <button style="margin-top: 2px;" id="submit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" 
   value="address">Save changes</button>
```

Comment: if you provide a fiddle i'll provide a solution

Comment: @KevinLynch I created a fiddle,  I have never created one b/4.. but I see I am getting an error in reference to the map.  Not sure what is causing it.  Here is the fiddle.. I made as close similar to my main program which is too big to load. https://jsfiddle.net/jaydreese/80aeugL4/28/

Comment: OK 3rd time is a charm.. the modal works but i'm still getting an error from the map script I believe... I did not my KEY in the google script...  is there a way to use a temp key for sharing this?  here is coreected jfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jaydreese/80aeugL4/82/

Comment: @KevinLynch ok I fixed the map issue and everything works accept you will need to add a KEY for google script.  Thanks for taking a look -  Here is the updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/jaydreese/80aeugL4/84/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't get your map (in the fiddle you provided) to work so I'm using an example I put together a while ago for a similar issue. In my example I pass the `lat/lng` to the javascript via data attributes within the html.

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/0utyjx9m/

```
  // Re-init map before show modal
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    initializeGMap(button.data('lat'), button.data('lng'));
    $("#location-map").css("width", "100%");
    $("#map_canvas").css("width", "100%");
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP code is not active in JavaScript code.

Here

```
{ 'address': <?php echo $row['OfficeAddress']; ?>}
```

value of address in not change.

Comment: You're close, but unless its stored as an JS escaped string with quotes around it this wont work.